# spark data frame not able to replace NULL values

Tags: apache-spark, pyspark, apache-spark-sql

Below code working fine, but if any one field is `NULL` out of 5 columns `SAL1, SAL2, SAL3, SAL4, SAL5` the corresponding `TOTAL_SALARY` is coming as `NULL`. 
Looks like some null condition or spark udfs need to create, could you please help in that.

input:

```py
NO NAME ADDR SAL1 SAL2 SAL3 SAL4 SAL5
1  ABC  IND  100  200  300  null 400
2  XYZ  USA  200  333  209  232  444
```

The second record's sum coming fine, but in first record because of null in `SAL4`, the output also coming as null.

```py
from pyspark.shell import spark
from pyspark.sql import functions as F
from pyspark.sql.types import StringType
sc = spark.sparkContext

df = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("C:\\TEST.txt")
df.createOrReplaceTempView("table1")
df1 = spark.sql( "select * from table1" )
df2 = df1.groupBy('NO', 'NAME', 'ADDR').agg(F.sum(df1.SAL1 + df1.SAL2 + df1.SAL3 + df1.SAL4 + df1.SAL5).alias("TOTAL_SALARY"))
df2.show()
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Basically below line of code check all 5 SAL fields and if it is null, replace it with 0. If not keep the original value.

```
df1 = df.withColumn("SAL1", when(df.SAL1.isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(df.SAL1))\
            .withColumn("SAL2", when(df.SAL2.isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(df.SAL2))\
            .withColumn("SAL3", when(df.SAL3.isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(df.SAL3))\
            .withColumn("SAL4", when(df.SAL4.isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(df.SAL4))\
            .withColumn("SAL5", when(df.SAL5.isNull(), lit(0)).otherwise(df.SAL5))\
```

Answer (score 0):

Just put a `na.fill(0)` in your code. This would replace the NULL values with 0 and you should be able to perform the operation.

So your last line should look like:

```
df2 = df1.na.fill(0).groupBy('NO', 'NAME', 'ADDR').agg(F.sum(df1.SAL1 + df1.SAL2 + df1.SAL3 + df1.SAL4 + df1.SAL5).alias("TOTAL_SALARY"))
```

It also seems that the `sum` function should be able to handle Null values correctly. I just tested the following code:

```
df_new = spark.createDataFrame([
(1, 4), (2, None),  (3,None), (4,None),
(5,5), (6,None), (7,None),(1, 4), (2, 8),  (3,9), (4,1),(1, 2), (2, 1), (3,3), (4,7),
], ("customer_id", "balance"))
df_new.groupBy("customer_id").agg(sum(col("balance"))).show()
df_new.na.fill(0).groupBy("customer_id").agg(sum(col("balance"))).show()
```

Output:

```
+-----------+------------+
|customer_id|sum(balance)|
+-----------+------------+
|          7|        null|
|          6|        null|
|          5|           5|
|          1|          10|
|          3|          12|
|          2|           9|
|          4|           8|
+-----------+------------+
+-----------+------------+
|customer_id|sum(balance)|
+-----------+------------+
|          7|           0|
|          6|           0|
|          5|           5|
|          1|          10|
|          3|          12|
|          2|           9|
|          4|           8|
+-----------+------------+
```

Version 1 only contains NULL values if all values in the sum are NULL.
Version 2 returns 0 instead, since all NULL values are replaced with 0's

Comment: I updated, but still it is failing when null or blank values are there

Comment: When we loaded input to spark sql dataframe it is showing as null values where ever blank filed is there in input txt file (1,2,3,,,).

Comment: I have tried by assigning to a new data frame. But still nulls are there.

Comment: Well then it seems, that it does not directly depend on the Null values. Why do you create this TempView in first place? you could directly work with `df`. It would also be good if you can include some output for your example. For example `df1.show()` before the groupBy and the result of the `df2.show()`

Comment: Still i'm having issue, i changed code as per below :
from pyparsing import col
from pyspark.shell import spark
sc = spark.sparkContext

newDF = spark.read.option("header","true").option("delimiter", ",").csv("C:\\TEST.txt")
df = newDF.na.fill(0).groupBy('YEAR').agg(sum(col("JAN") + col("FEB")))
df.show()

Error: while 2nd line giving below error
TypeError: col() missing 1 required positional argument: 'strg'

Comment: i'm using pyspark 2.3.0

Comment: Updated sample original input data in the above, below to balance table.

Comment: it works perfectly fine for me. But I'm using the `col()` function from sql.functions (http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html#pyspark.sql.functions.col) I think you imported another function which requires 2 arguments and that is why you get the error

Comment: Your above example is working, means if we are creating a data frame by hard coding values, in this case null values are replacing zeros. But, if we are loading a csv/txt file as i mentioned above, in this case nulls are not replacing.

Comment: with below code, i'm getting the below mentioned output:
df.select('*', coalesce(df["SAL1"], lit(0.0)))\
    .select('*', coalesce(df_new5["SAL2"], lit(0.0)))

Comment: +---+-----+----+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
| NO| NAME|DEPT|SAL1|SAL2|coalesce(SAL1, 0.0)|coalesce(SAL2, 0.0)|
+---+-----+----+----+----+-------------------+-------------------+
|  1|  ABC|  IT|null| 900|                0.0|                900|
|  2|  XYZ|  HR| 600| 800|                600|                800|
|  3|  RAM|null| 700| 900|                700|                900|
|  4| HARI|  HR| 800| 300|                800|                300|
|  5|  SAM|  IT| 950|null|                950|                0.0|
+---+-----+----+----+----+-------------------+-----

Comment: 2 UPDATES I NEED NOW :
1.To change 2 column names which are with coalesce
2.Same these 2 columns sum i need in another column.